# Ivy: org.apache.ws.commons.schema#XmlSchema version 1.4.3 evicting version 1.4.7 via latest-revision conflict manager

Tags: maven, ivy

I noticed that XmlScheme from the org.apache.ws.commons.schema project is having version 1.4.3 evict version 1.4.7 when there's a conflict. Here's the information in my Ivy report:

#### Revision: 1.4.7 (evicted by 1.4.3)

```
Home Page      http://ws.apache.org/commons/XmlSchema
Status         release
Publication    20120814141749
Resolver       public
Configurations compile, master(*), compile(*), master
Artifacts size 0 kB (0 kB downloaded, 0 kB in cache)
Licenses       The Apache Software License, Version 2.0
Evicted by     1.4.3 in latest-revision conflict manager
```

#### Revision 1.4.3

```
Home Page      http://ws.apache.org/commons/XmlSchema
Status         release
Publication    20120823164341
Resolver       public
Configurations compile, master(*), runtime, compile(*), runtime(*), master
Artifacts size 140 kB (140 kB downloaded, 0 kB in cache)
Licenses       The Apache Software License, Version 2.0
```

Note how 1.4.7 has a Publication date of ***14-Aug-2012 (at 14:17:49)*** and 1.4.3 has a Publication date of ***23-Aug-2012 (at 16:43:41)***. That would make version 1.4.3 later. However, when I look at my corporate Maven repository (Nexus), it has the following information:

```
Artifact:    XmlSchema-1.4.3.jar
Path:        org/apache/ws/commons/schema/XmlSchema/1.4.3   
Modified:    10-12-08 16:22:52 CST
Cache:       repo1-cache

Artifact:    XmlSchema-1.4.3.pom
Path:        org/apache/ws/commons/schema/XmlSchema/1.4.3
Modified:    10-12-08 16:22:52 CST
Cache:       repo1-cache

Artifact:   XmlSchema-1.4.7.jar
Path:       org/apache/ws/commons/schema/XmlSchema/1.4.7
Modified:   22-09-10 16:32:41 CDT
Cache:      repo1-cache

Artifact:   XmlSchema-1.4.7.pom 
Path:       org/apache/ws/commons/schema/XmlSchema/1.4.7
Modified:   22-09-10 16:32:43 CDT
Cache:      repo1-cache
```

(The `repo1-cache` is a cache for `http://search.maven.org`)

Where is it getting those *Publication* dates from? The dates in my Maven repository seem to agree with the publication dates in the public Maven repo, but the Ivy Publication dates are completely different.

Answer (score 0):

The publication date comes from the value of the `publication` attribute of the `info` element in the `ivy.xml` for the artifact within your cache. This value is set by Ivy when it fetches the artifact and is thus the date and time that the copy of the artifact was created in your Ivy cache. You should be able to confirm this by clearing out your Ivy cache, forcing Ivy to fetch the artifacts from your corporate Nexus repository once again and then looking at the generated reports.